# Unable to delete first node in circular linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

Alright, I'm trying to do this for an assignment. Been having an issue with my sorted circular linked list. I'm able to add and remove things just fine, with one exception. That exception being the first node in the list. It crashes on "if (location.getInfo().equals(target))", in the find method, everytime. I have no idea why and need help. It spits a null pointer error message and narrows it down to the above message. If I input, for example, Adam, it adds it to the list and tallies it appropriately. But, when I go to remove the item, it runs the find method and NPEs on the find method. I've tried both .equals(target) and ==, both give the NPE.

```
protected void find(T target)
{
    location = list;
    found = false;

    if(list != null)
    {
        System.out.println("\nFinding: " + target);
        do
        {
            previous = location; // move search to the next node
            location = location.getLink();

            if (location.getInfo().equals(target))*// checks for a match
            {
                System.out.println(target + " was found.");
                found = true;
            }
        } 
        while ((location != list) && !found);
    }
}
```

And here's my `LLNode.java`:

```
public class LLNode<T> 
    {
    private LLNode<T> link;
    private T info;

    public LLNode(T info)
    {
        this.info = info;
        link = null;
    }

    public void setInfo(T info)
    {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public T getInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }

    public void setLink(LLNode<T> link)
    {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public LLNode<T> getLink()
    {
        return link;
    } 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, here is my add method:

```
public void add(T element)
{
    LLNode<T> prevLoc;
    LLNode<T> location;
    T listElement;

    if (!element.equals(""))
    {   
        LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(element);
        if(list == null)
        {
            list = newNode;
            newNode.setLink(list);
        }
        else if (list.getInfo().compareTo(element) > 0)
        {
            newNode.setLink(list.getLink());
            list.setLink(newNode);
            list = newNode;
        }
        else if (list.getInfo().compareTo(element) < 0)
        {
            newNode.setLink(list.getLink());
            list.setLink(newNode);

        }
        else
        {
            location = list.getLink();
            prevLoc = null;
            while (location != list)
            {

                listElement = location.getInfo();
                if (listElement.compareTo(element) < 0)
                {
                    prevLoc = location;
                    location = location.getLink();
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }// Insert node into list
            if (prevLoc == null)
            {
                // Insert as first node
                newNode.setLink(list);
                list = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                // Insert elsewhere
                newNode.setLink(location);
                prevLoc.setLink(newNode);
            }
        }
        numElements++;  
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("\nReturning to the main menu.");
    }
}
```

Hopefully, this helps narrow down where the problem with my code is.

Comment: You apparantly get a NPE for `location.getInfo()`. It does not matter if you try to use `.equals()` or `==` after that, because the code does not run that far. It would appear that one of your links is null. Check the return value of `location.getLink()`.

Comment: Add a println for location and location.getInfo() and you will see which is null. Without seeing insertion it is hard to tell what is going wrong but my money is on a link being null or info. You start checking the second element in the list, so probably at the wrap-around.

Comment: It definitely prints null. The System.out.println("Link: "+location.getLink()); that is.

Comment: You simply have to test and debug until you figure it out.  Linked lists are *hard*, and you should expect to have some bugs.  This is what separates the men from the boys.  Thought is required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the `add` method:

```
while (location != null)
```

So the method expects `location` to sometimes be `null`. That means the list is not circular but has an end.

In the `find` method:

```
do {
     if (location.getInfo().equals(target))
     ...
} while ((location != list) && !found);
```

So the method expects `location` to never be `null`, like in a circular list.

In a circular list all elements in the list point to another element in the list (in a circle). 

When the list has one element, it will point to itself.

When the list has 2 elements, each will point to the other, and so on.

In a normal linked-list, the last element will always point to `null` and the code needs to expect that.